# comma separated foreach

Tags: php, foreach

The idea is to get a comma separated list of products, but that list must contain "product_name (pipe) product_price*quantity"
For example, if the order contained 2xABC (at $10.00) and 3xDEF (at $20.00), my output would need to be "`ABC|20.00,DEF|60.00`"
I have the following code:

```
    $products = $db->Execute($products_query);
    while (!$products->EOF) {
        $purchasedArray[] = array('products_name'=>$products->fields['products_name'],
                                    'final_price'=>$products->fields['final_price'],
                                    'products_quantity'=>$products->fields['products_quantity']);
        $products->MoveNext();
      }
```

Then, I run a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
    $list .= $purchased['products_name'] . '|' . ($purchased['final_price']*$purchased['products_quantity']);
}
```

and want to output the result:

```
$listFinal = implode(','. $list);
echo $listFinal;
```

But, as usual, I'm missing something and this doesn't work. :) Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I get the following error in my error logs and nothing echoes: `PHP Warning:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Argument must be an array in line XXX` (referring to `echo $listFinal;` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply concatenating a string, try this:

```
foreach ($purchasedArray as $purchased) {
    $formattedProducts[] = $purchased['products_name'] . '|' . ($purchased['final_price']*$purchased['products_quantity']);
}

$listFinal = implode(',', $formattedProducts);
echo $listFinal;
```

Comment: When I try the exact same code (`$products` to be precise), I get an fatal error "Cannot use object of type queryFactoryResult as array" and if I use `$list[]` instead, then I get `PHP Warning:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Argument must be an array`

Comment: You can't use `$list` as an array, b/c you have it set as a string, hence why `implode` is not working. You set the `foreach` loop exactly as I described in my answer? `$products` is simply an array of strings constructed by each iteration's associative elements; products_name, final_price, etc. Can you post the `var_dump($purchasedArray)`?

Comment: yes, I c/p your code. I believe the `$products` can't be used because it's already being used in the DB query and while? dunno... :) here's the var_dump: [link]http://codepad.org/e2lzHTE2

Comment: Ya, you are correct, I didn't see that `$products` was already assigned, just change the `$products` in the `foreach` loop to something else, I updated answer to use `$formattedProducts`, but feel free to use whatever you want.

Comment: WTF?!?! why didn't this work with `$list[]` ? I did the exact same thing, but I used `$list` instead of `$formattedProducts` and it didn't work and now this works... I'm totally confused. But, nevermind, THANK YOU very much for the assistance!

Comment: It didn't work with `$list[]`, because you had it as `$list .=`. The former is an array, on which implode will work, the latter is a string being concatenated to for every iteration, and which implode will not work.